# A tool for collaborative calendar editing with ics feeds export and recurring events?

Tags: calendar, collaboration

Are you aware of any? Preferably a self-hosted open source app. Preferably with unlimited "hierarchy" of calendars (like, if `calendar A` is a child of `calendar B` then requesting a `ics` feed from `calendar B` should also include all events in `A`). I was thinking of something like a mailman but for calendars (probably also manageable through email exchange).

- [calagator](http://calagator.org) seems to have some issues with recurring events (like, "every M, W at 3pm")
- [teamup](https://www.teamup.com/) seems to have these features, however they only allow very limited number of sub-calendars and only hierarchy of depth two, afaik

Anything else?